# pubsub (gcp iam) using firebase auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I'm writing an (embedded + mobile) app that uses firestore through REST & GRPC APIs.  Each access authenticates using firebase bearer tokens which is identifies a firebase userid.

I'd like to use that same token/firebase uid to pull notifications from pubsub, and limit that firebase uid to a particular topic, but pubsub uses gcp's IAM, not firestore authentication .  How can I reference the firebase users on pubsub/iam ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the token or firebase UID to authenticate and pull data from Google Cloud Pub/Sub isn't possible and really won't scale. Cloud Pub/Sub has tighter [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas) on number of topics and number of subscriptions per topic: 10,000 for each. It is designed for the "torrents" use case: a smaller number of topics and subscriptions to which a lot of data is delivered. Firestore scales in a different direction, to much larger numbers of end users. Therefore, you will quickly run out of quota for individual subscriptions on Cloud Pub/Sub.

Instead, you'd want some kind of frontend server that subscribers to the desired Cloud Pub/Sub topics and distributes messages to the end users, perhaps via [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), which is more of the "trickles" use case where there are many, many topics on which a small number of messages are published.

Comment: I knew about that 10000 limitation, and was hoping I could get bye until the value listen feature is available on firestore

As for FCM, I don't think will work because the end device is embeded linux, and even with node (js)  I think the infrastructure isn't there for it to work ... needs to be a browser/phone/tablet

Also, I tried IOT core (config updates), and it looked promising, however the MQTT bridge does not allow persistent connections ... so it would work like polling which is not going to work for me, unless I do very frequent polling which I think would be cost prohibitive.